# xorg.conf with NVidia on NFS Users

Tags: nvidia, nfs, xorg

i'm running a Red Hat EL 5.7 workstation with some NFS users mounted on a server. I have to set NVidia parameters to dual screen with xinerama and save the X configuration file, that's ok, but when i login the first time in every user included root, the second monitor doesn't turn on and when i login the second time it works, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read Xorg's log to discover. It's usually `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.